# Javascript this and that

Tags: javascript

```
<script>
    var model;
    $(document).ready(
        function() {
            console.log("Document ready invoked!!");
            model = new ModelContainer({container:$('#containerX')[0]});

            var that = model;
            window.addEventListener( 'resize', that.update, false );
        }
    );

    ModelContainer = function(param) {

        this.containerID = param.container.id;
        this.containerWidth = param.container.offsetWidth;
        this.containerHeight = param.container.offsetHeight;

        console.log("Container ID width and height :", this.containerID, this.containerWidth, this.containerHeight);

    }

    ModelContainer.prototype.update = function () {

        console.log("Update called invoked");
        this.containerWidth = $(this.containerID).offsetWidth;
        this.containerHeight = $(this.containerID).offsetHeight;

        console.log("Container ID width and height :", this.containerID, this.containerWidth, this.containerHeight);

    }

</script>
```

I am trying to understand the use of 'that' in update method. this.containerId is undefined.
Any help to understand why "that.update" fails when called from the listener method would be  appreciated.

Comment: there's no `that` in the update method. only in the document ready event handler.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It needs to be like this:

```
window.addEventListener( 'resize', function() {that.update()}, false );
```

It doesn't work the way you had it because all that gets passed to addEventListener is a reference to the `update()` method.  The value of `that` is not passed.  Further, inside the addEventListener callback, the value of `this` will be set to the object that caused the event, not your model.

So, to rectify this, you pass a shell function to `addEventListener()` and then inside that shell function, you call the `obj.method()` that you actually want called and calling it this way will get the right value of `this` inside your method.

In your code, you can't use the `model` variable in the event callback because it's not a local variable so therefore it could be changed to some other value by the time you need it.  But, by assigning it to a local variable, you can assure that it's value will be the right value when the callback function is called and thus it can be used inside the callback function.

This is a common tool when callback functions need access to a variable that might not remain unchanged between the time the event listener is installed and the time that the event actually occurs (and the callback is called).

You could also just do this if nobody else needs access to the `model` variable:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
        console.log("Document ready invoked!!");
        var model = new ModelContainer({container:$('#containerX')[0]});

        window.addEventListener( 'resize', function() {model.update()}, false );
    }
);
```

There is no particular need to have a variable named `that` - you just need a variable in the right scope that won't be messed with by other code.

Comment: The only use I can see for *that* is it to allow the global *model* to reference the last created instance of *ModelContainer*. Dunno if that is important or not. Otherwise I think our answers are about identical.

Comment: Thank you. Amazing .. you guys are just amazing